# Storing SSIS Execution Results in to a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I'm in SQL Server 2008 and created a few SSIS packages. I would like to know if we have any standard approach to dump all execution results into a table to track the status of packages instead of taking output into a screenshot.

I have implemented Package Logging in my SSIS package and executed it. , I selected SSIS log provider for SQL Server and selected an OLEDB connection for configuration, selected events to be logged. But, I'm not sure where to look for after executing package. Can anyone please advise where I can see the results stored? I thought it might be creating a table automatically, which seems not to be the case!!

To be more clear, I started off with this MSDN Link [Enable Package Logging in SQL Server Data Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141212.aspx)

Comment: Is your server SQL 2008 or a higher version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It creates a table in System Tables of the relevant DB with the name 'sysssislog'.

If you are using SSMS, expand Database, expand Tables, expand System Tables, you would see the table dbo.sysssislog.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a 'standard' approach - but it works well, and it's easy to implement.

At the start of the package, have an execute sql task 'Write ETL Log' which adds a timestamp, package description, and details into an ETL Log table:

```
INSERT INTO [Staging].[dbo].[ETL_Log] VALUES ('2015-07-28 16:41:32','ETL Process ABC','Started...')
```

At the end of the package, I have another execute sql task which does something like this:

```
INSERT INTO [Staging].[dbo].[ETL_Log] VALUES ('2015-07-28 16:47:40','ETL Process ABC','Complete. A:\floppitout.bas has been successfully loaded')
```

This makes it easy to record the pertinent details that you need to a table with minimal superfluous information. You can write a stored proc to check this table for jobs that have started and not finished, or jobs that you expected to run but that haven't run at all. Good luck.

Comment: I implemented this already. The log I wanted to track is of execution results of SSIS package but not the Log we add as part of business logic / validation.